# How To Disable AutoFill For Combobox using c#?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have added combo boxes/Auto Complete Textbox to display several lists but after clicking the Drop_down it is auto filled with google services which in turns hide the combo_box list. I have added code(Custom view, Custom Renderers and other necessary classes) of XfX.Control Nuget Package. Provided is the link from where I have downloaded the NuGet package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xfx.Controls
Besides this when I change the Auto Fill services of my phone to None from Google the list appears as it is. [This is how the combobox looks like.its hiding defined list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YL70N.jpg)